# Creative X-Fi HD (USB Sound Card)

Tags: drivers

I connect my sound card to a Ubuntu 12.10 machine and it seems to work but, when I try to listen anythings, the sound is corrupted.
The device works fine if I connect to a win machine, so I think it is due to a bad driver.
Could someone tell me how I can fix the problem?

Thank you in advance!
Bye,
Emiliano

Answer (score 0):

I have this card too, and I wish Creative had something to do with it but they do nothing for Linux (except the driver they couldn't finish).
If you are a big brain - look for your driver at [alsa-project.org](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aVendor-Creative_Labs). Let's hope you will have time and knowledge to fix it.

BTW, now my Ubuntu shows absolutely no sound output devices.